# bilateral feedback analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, feedback, stability

[This](http://www.utdallas.edu/~chiu.yun/courses/7326/handout/feedback.pdf) is an article about bilateral feedback analysis.

Could anyone explain the what is meant by this sentence?

> The most important fact about this circuit is the symmetric bilateral transmission through the feedback impedance \$Z_{F}\$ albeit the forward amplifier is still unilateral.

What does "symmetric bilateral transmission" mean here?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the purpose of ZF? Answer: To provide a feedback path that produces a voltage across ZS||Zin. This feedback voltage is superimposed with a corresponding part of the "normal" signal input voltage Vi at the opamp input node.

However, this is an ideal case that happens only if there would be an output impedance Zo=0. If Zo has a finite value, a part of the input signal Vi arrives directly at the output (and NOT only via the forward amplifier Voc). This portion depends on the voltage divider Zo/(Zs+ZF+Zo). This neglects the large Zin.

That means: The feedback path works in both directions: (1) As wanted: From the output back to the input and (2) Not desired but unavoidable: Directly from the input to the output.

By the way: We face the same situation with a feedback resistor connected between the collector node and the base node of a transistor stage. This is the principle behind the so called "Miller-Effect".

It is a remaining question why this example circuit has positive feedback (perhaps just a drawing error ?).

**EDIT:** In equ. (2) we can introduce the following ideal values: Zin infinite, Zo=0 and the open-loop gain k as infinite. In this case, we arrive at **A=-ZF/ZS** . This is the classical inverting gain for an ideal opamp with negative feedback. Hence, in the shown circuit we have to exchange the non-inv. and the inv. input (drawing error).

Comment: About feedback sign, maybe k<0...

Comment: In this case (k<0), what is the meaning of the +/- signs at the input nodes?

Comment: Giving the references for Vg. To know the sign of feedback you need both the input references and the OL gain sign.

Comment: I disagree. The + sign at the input node tells us that the output voltage is an amplified version of the input voltage WITHOUT phase inversion (for low frequencies including DC). This applies to ALL amplifiers with a differential input. Is there any counter example?

Comment: I am not sure this conversation can lead to any profitable result. The references of the input indicates that a voltage applied to the input, and measured respecting those references, will be presented at the output, multiplied by the (possibly negative) gain. Any fully diff opamp set up to express negative gain falls in this category. I agree that in the book there probably is a typo, and that such a convention is misleading, but hey, it is just a convention. I am not trying to prove any particular point, just provide an easy solution to a possible typo.

Comment: Yes - it is a convention, of course. But what is the purpose of a + sign at the input without knowing if inside the symbol is a "possibly negative" gain block or not? Therefore, the convention is as mentioned in my foregoing comment. (May I add - i did not start this conversation).

Comment: Thank you very much, LvW. 
Could you explain this part "However, this is an ideal case that happens only if there would be an output impedance Zo=0. If Zo has a finite value, a part of the input signal Vi arrives directly at the output (and NOT only via the forward amplifier Voc). This portion depends on the voltage divider Zo/(ZF+Zo)." Do you mean that with Z0 = 0, the input voltage don't affect to output voltage? 

I don't get this. Even with Z0 = 0, the voltage across Zin will be changed by ZF and so the output voltage will also vary with input voltage.

Comment: anhna, for a finite value of Zo a part of the input voltage arrives DIRECTLY across Zo (via ZF). Therefore we have two voltages at the output node: The amplified voltage (as always) and a small portion that is caused by the voltage divider Zo/(Zo+ZF). This last portion is not desired because ZF is intended to act only from the output back to the input - but this effect cannot be avoided for a finite Zo. Hence, we have the case of "bilateral feedback" (a large feedback signal and a smaller "forward" signal). That is the meaning of "bilateral feedback".

Comment: anhna, did you realize the sign error in the shown circuit? (see my EDIT).

Comment: " for a finite value of Zo a part of the input voltage arrives DIRECTLY across Zo (via ZF). Therefore we have two voltages at the output node: The amplified voltage (as always) and a small portion that is caused by the voltage divider Zo/(Zo+ZF)."
With input voltage, did you mean the voltage across two terminals of OpAmp not the input voltage Vi from the schematic?
Also, if we take Vi as the input voltage (shown in picture above), there will be a part of input voltage (Vi) arrives directly across Zs, ZF, to output even Zo is zero. 
Is that right?

Comment: LvW, thanks for the explanation! I see the drawing error after reading your post now.

Comment: anhnha, with "input voltage" I mean the applied signal voltage Vi as shown in the schematic. To be more exact, I have corrected the relevant voltage divider expression in my detailed answer. It must be Zo/(Zs+ZF+Zo). Regarding your last question: Of course, we have a current through Zs and ZF and, hence, corresponding voltages. However, the UNWANTED part at the ouput appears only for a finite value of Zo. For this, imagine that the opamp does not amplify. In this case you have a resistive chain Zs-ZF-ZO only, driven by Vi. Now, a voltage Vo does exist for a finite Zo only.

Comment: Thank you. I understand it now. 
As you said, Vout is composed of two components: direct path from Vin via ZF and the second component from Vin to Vout via amplifier.
So is it possible to calculate Vout by superposition?

Comment: Correct - you can apply superposition.

Comment: Could you give detail how superposition is applied here? 
I couldn't see how to use it. For superposition, there should be at least two sources. However, for the circuit above, I only see only one source Vin. What is the other source for superposition?

Comment: There are two sources: (1) Vin causes a (smaller) output voltage  without phase inversion Vo1=+Vi*Zo/(Zs+ZF+Zo) (assuming the opamp output Voc=0) and (2) the opamp ouput voltage Voc causes another (larger) portion Vo2=-Voc*(Zs+ZF)/(Zo+ZF+Zs). The output voltage Voc can be found using the classical expression for an inverting opamp.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to sum Vo1 and Vo2 with Voc = k*Vin*Zin/(Zin+Zs) to get Vout. However, the result doesn't same as the closed loop gain given in (2) in the picture above. Is there something wrong here?

Comment: Yes - something wrong. As I said: Vo2 is the output voltage of the classical inverting opamp amplifier (with feedback!) - however, without the portion which arrives "directly" via ZF at the output. That means: For vo2, forget the bilateral aspect and treat the circuit as a classical inverter.

Answer (score 2):

In this context it basically means that Zf transmits signals in both directions.

Look at the amplifier model you are using - just the amplifier, take out all the surrounding components. If you force Vo from the outside, would this produce something at the amplifier input, i.e. across Zin? **No**.

Now take your Zf, make the same experiment... And you quickly understand that the same thing does not apply.

A *unilateral* system lets signals propagate in a unique direction, i.e. from one port to another, while a *bilateral* system allows the signal to go in both directions.

Symmetric here means that you can swap input and output and nothing changes: if you reverse Zf, nothing changes. Think of Zf as a generic two port system. For such a system you usually have two distinct transfer functions, one from port A to port B, the other from port B to port A. If the two transfer functions are identical the system is symmetrical, i.e. its ports are indistinguishable, and if you swap them nothing changes.

This is probably stressed in your textbook because the fact that Zf is not unilateral influences the closed loop gain transfer function in a non trivial way.

Comment: Quote: "Symmetric here means that you can swap input and output and nothing changes: if you reverse Zf, nothing changes." I must admit that I do not understand this part of the answer (...nothing changes). Please, can you explain?

Comment: What I mean is that a two port system, such as an impedance, is symmetrical iff its ports are indistinguishable. I will clarifiy this in the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much the answer Vladimir Cravero and LvW for the question. That is also what I was confused.

Comment: OK - and in the present case, the "two-port system" is simply a passive part Z ? But - is this an answer to a question regarding bilateral feedback?

Comment: If you feel my answer is incomplete or not clear please do edit it. I am not sure I understand your latest remark, unfortunately.

Comment: What I mean is the following: In your answer you explain that a passive two-port is symmetrical and allows bilateral operation (certainly true). But the OP was asking for bilateral "feedback" which requires an answer to the question: "Why does such bilateral signal flow exist in the given circuit". Do you know what I mean?